# Javafx Textfield: Accept only digits of length 8 or 11 ( phone numbers)

Tags: javafx, textfield, phone-number

Working on a project with javafx and I'm having a minor hitch. I want my textfield to accept only digits, 8 or 11 in length. Here's my code:

```
if(!txtPhone.getText().matches(.....) && (txtPhone.getText().length != 8 || txtPhone.getText(). length != 11){
System.out.print("Please enter a valid phone number");
}
```

Comment: You want the error message to be displayed if one of the criterions is satisfied, right? Currently the expression in the brackets always evaluates to `true` (after fixing the syntax errors): The text length is always different to 8, 11 or both. This makes the expression logically equivalent to `!txtPhone.getText().matches(.....)`. You probably intended to use `String text = texttPhone.getText(); if (!(((text.length() == 11) || (text.length() == 8)) && text.matches("\\d*")))` (Note that I reordered the conditions a bit, since comparing the string lenght takes less time than matching the regex.)

Comment: Using de morgan you could write the condition in the above comment to `!text.matches("\\d*") || (text.length() != 8 && text.length() != 11)`, i.e. it's an error, if the text doesn't contain only digits or if the text lenght is different to both allowed lenghts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expression can be used to create custom validations.

```
if (txtPhone.getText().matches("\\d{8}|\\d{11}") {

    System.out.println("Its Valid Number");
    //return true;
}else {

    System.out.println("Invalid Input..!");
    //return false;
}
```

You can learn and check about Regular Expressions [Here](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The task involves two stages:

- You must first create a text box that accepts digits only (up to 11 maximum).
- Second, you have to customize the user input according to your criteria (8 or 11 digits)

[TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) is used to solve the problem. A [UnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) must be passed to it to filter user input only by numbers and [StringConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html) to validate user input.

This is an example implementation:

```
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = change -> {
    if(change.getControlNewText().matches("\\d{0,11}")) {
        return change;
    }

    return null;
};

StringConverter<String> converter = new StringConverter<String>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(String s) {
        if(s == null || s.isBlank()) return "";

        if(s.matches("\\d{8}|\\d{11}")) {
            return s;
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String fromString(String s) {
        if(s == null || s.isBlank()) return "";

        if(s.matches("\\d{8}|\\d{11}")) {
            return s;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Converter error");
    }
};

textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(converter, null, filter));
```

Comment: Thanks @mr mcwolf. How do I fit these into the if statement above, in a line of code?

Comment: @JohnOmage, the `if` operator above is practically useless. It simply prints text in the console. And this in the context of the GUI only makes sense as a debug output. If so, paste tracking messages into the body of `StringConverter::fromString`.

Comment: It seems more likely that you want to notify the user that he or she did not enter the phone number before proceeding. Therefore, there are several possible approaches: disable the OK button, disable the dialog closing with the corresponding message, or simply show a notification (icon, text ...) that the field is blank. How exactly to do this is impossible to say since there is no additional information.